# Lightning console methods does not respond after keeping console tabs open for sometime

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, performance, console, chrome

There is a wired behavior observed in our lightning console app.
After few tabs and subtabs opens up and we keep the browser open for an hour or so,

the lightning methods top open tab and subtabs stops responding.
Though opening a modal popup still works fine so I cannot say its a freeze.

Here is a debug view, when I click a case.
I have set debug points on Javascript side to check if the debug points are hit.

It does hit the point and has the instance too, but it does not open up the subtab, neither the promise sends any error response.

[image]

Image to show that objWorkSpaceAPi has the instance :

[image]

But if I refresh the page with F5, and then if I try the same flow, it opens up the subtab properly.

**Update**

There are almost 18000, error logs generated in Console tab in chrome from aura_prod.js `uncaught exception : getTabInfo()`. Can this slow down performance, or disable the workspace api functionality?

**UPDATE 2**

We also have 6 setIntervals(500) written to fire the result from primary tab to subtabs. Each interval fires from each component in the Primary Tab to its component in the subTab, so that subTabs dont have to do a callout. 
As we know that a user can open multiple primary tabs but be active only on one tab at a time. And setIntervals execution is prioritized low by default in the inactive tabs, can this also be a reason why the browser performance gets low progressively.

Any help would be appreciated? This is happening in production (Lightning console application).

Comment: Hi @Nagendra Singh, Do you have a solution for this problem. At present I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @indrasenneelam The issue here was, at the time on this implementation, you can open any number of Tabs and Subtabs in lightning console app. And we had some heavy customizations in each of those tabs and subtabs. `setintervals` firing messages every 500 ms etc.  And too many VF pages also added on flexipage. Thus it looked  like a performance issue.